# How to avoid the external user to link to /cmspages/logon.aspx

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

How to avoid external users to link on /cmspages/logon.aspx.

I want when they will type the www.domainname.com/cmspages/logon.aspx to block them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it really depends on what you mean by an external user.

One approach I've taken before when I only want people within my office/network to be able to access the Admin pages, it to use an IP lockdown via the [UrlRewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) extension. This approach works in IIS (once the extension is installed) and Azure App Services.

A rule something like this should do the trick:

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="cmspages*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="45.56.78.*" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="401" statusReason="Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials" statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
</rule>
```

This will block access to all `cmspages` (possibly too agressive) if the IP of the visitor does not match the given pattern.